Kamal (Ruby on Rails) is not able to resolve environmental variables or paths
My rails application has the following

Dockerfile
config/deploy.yml
.env

I am trying to do
kamal env push
INFO [55b3675b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal on ${SERVER_IP}
ERROR (Socket::ResolutionError): Exception while executing on host ${SERVER_IP}: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.

Whatever I do, I am not able to get kamal resolve my variables from .env file, it works if I hard code all the variables into the deploy.yml itself
What am I doing wrong? I have no clue how to debug as well.
In fact even when I am trying to give path for my private key which is in my ~\.ssh\id_rsa, it is not able to find it! I had to put the private key itself in my deploy.yml to make it work.
( I am using git bash in windows)
My deploy.yml looks like this
# Name of your application. Used to uniquely configure containers.
service: myapp

# Name of the container image.
image: ${DOCKER_USERNAME}/myapp

# Deploy to these servers.
servers:
  web:
    - ${SERVER_IP}

# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  username: 
    - ${DOCKER_USERNAME}
  password: 
    - ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}

# Inject ENV variables into containers.
env:
  clear:
    REDIS_URL: ${REDIS_URL}
    DOMAIN: ${DOMAIN}
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL

# Use accessory services.
accessories:
  redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine
    host: ${SERVER_IP}
    port: 6379

# Configure custom arguments for Traefik.
traefik:
  args:
    entryPoints.web.address: ":80"
    entryPoints.websecure.address: ":443"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint: "web"
  options:
    publish:
      - "443:443"
    volume:
      - "/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"

# Configure a custom healthcheck
healthcheck:
  path: /up
  port: 3000

asset_path: /rails/public

boot:
  limit: 25%
  wait: 5

ssh:
  user: root
  keys: 
    - ${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH}



Hardcode IPs: Instead of using ${SERVER_IP} in your deploy.yml, just hardcode the IP addresses. This avoids any issues with variable resolution, especially on Windows.
List All Secrets: Under env: secret, make sure you list all the secret names you're using (e.g., RAILS_MASTER_KEY, DOCKER_PASSWORD). Kamal expects these to be there by name.
Lastly, I remember that you should upload you ssh key in the place that you're application is hosted.

If I am pushing my code to git, I don't want the IP to be sent to git. the purpose of .env is to keep the config separate from code (and code base), so hardcoding IP wouldn't be a good idea.
For the rest also, the same problem as SERVER_IP. Kamal is not able to read any variable from .env (that's the core problem).
For ssh, the key is used to connect to the server. So it is needed on my local machine! (Server will have the public key on known_hosts)

Have you try putting all the .env constants that you're using after the env -> secret ? Because right now I only see   - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
- LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL

what do you mean by env -> secret?

Inside you deploy.yml, you need to define the env constants that you're going to use in the rest of the file. Thats goes under env: { secret: } where right now you just have the RAILS_MASTER_KEY and LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL. So after them, add the rest of the constants that you need, like SERVER_IP and DOCKER_USERNAME and password.

Try using this syntax:
registry:
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

